# Which dataset organization for binary image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, classification

The ANN model I am working on must recognize a specific object in an image, and only this one. As the model has to give the probability that the object is in the image or not, how should be the organization of my dataset?

Can I split my data into 2 categories: "right object" and an "other" gathering random pictures, or do I have to create several "other" categories such as "birds", "devices", and so on?

Thanks.

EDIT: I did not find any post here nor website providing interesting tips on how to create a good image dataset.

Comment: creating several categories would help in better understanding of which object is present in image and then  output the most relevant category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I understood my question was not that relevant, because it can be solved after a few experiments and tests.

It is essential to have differents categories for the "other" objects, as they do not have the same features nor shapes. Creating a mixture of several objects in the same category can be very detrimental for the model's accuracy...

The priority (at least in my case) is to deal with objects that are similar to the ones I need to recognize.
For example, if I want to detect a Blu-ray player, I will have many electronic device categories to help my model to see the difference, like "keyboard", "screen", "computer" categories.